# android apk imagebutton click crashes

Tags: android, apk, imagebutton

I have been testing my app on my actual device and everything works perfect when I do a debug install.  But when I build the APK and install it, the app loads up fine to the main screen.  When I click one of the imagebuttons on the main screen, it crashes.  Again, only the apk build crashes upon imagebutton click, if I deploy the app to the device through debug or use the emulator, the app works perfect.

In my xml, here is an example of one of the buttons:

```
<ImageButton 
android:id="@+id/btnHomeServices"
android:src="@drawable/button_homeservices"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"    
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"                 
android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
android:background="@null"
android:onClick="HomeServicesClick"/>
```

And the click event method in code:

```
public void HomeServicesClick(View view)
{
    //we do some stuff here
}
```

I even commented out the code inside HomeServicesClick and it still crashes, so I know the problem is not the code its trying to execute in that method.

```
03-19 11:02:18.605: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18211): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 11:02:18.605: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18211): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method HomeServicesClick(View) in the activity class com.WhiteLabel.LoadingScreen for onClick handler on view class android.widget.ImageButton with id 'btnHomeServices'
03-19 11:02:18.605: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18211):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2178)
03-19 11:02:18.605: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18211):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
03-19 11:02:18.605: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18211):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9293)
03-19 11:02:18.605: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18211):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:587)
03-19 11:02:18.605: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18211):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
```

Comment: did you **Clean** your project?

Comment: I just tried it, no different.

Comment: does it run fine on emulator?

Comment: it runs fine on emulator and if i debug through device, but when i install apk this happens...see below

Answer (score 0):

Ahe answer is in the stack trace. From the command line, do "adb logcat" and then force the app to error. You will see a stack trace in the log that tells you exactly (well almost) what the error is.

Take a look at,

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick

It says,

> Name of the method in this View's context to invoke when the view is
> clicked. This name must correspond to a public method that takes
> exactly one parameter of type View. For instance, if you specify
> android:onClick="sayHello", you must declare a public void
> sayHello(View v) method of your context (typically, your Activity).

Comment: this only occurs when i install the app from the apk.  how am i supposed to use logcat?  also, this happens on any imagebutton click in the app.

Comment: again, the answer is in logcat. logcat is always running. it doesn't depend on you installing from eclipse (if that's what you are saying). you can run "adb logcat" from the command line, or you can just keep eclipse connected when you run the app.

Comment: This is good to know, I never knew it was always running...I got the error in eclipse (i already had a logcat tab).  java.lang.illegalstateexception: Could not find a method HomeServicesClick(View) in the activity class xxx for onClick handler on view class android.widget.ImageButton with id 'btnHomeServices'

Comment: see my update. where did you implement HomeServicesClick? and you should include the stack trace from logcat in your question.

Comment: I added it, like I said this all works fine when i use emulator or debug to device. its very strange. HomeServicesClick is in fact in the class com.WhiteLabel.LoadingScreen so I dont know what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you shouldn't specify onClick in your layout file if you are going to make a release build / use proguard. You should use setOnClickListener in the onCreate instead.

Comment: Really?  So this type of functionality is for debug purposes only?  I would like to see where it states that in the android docs.  But this makes sense.  I just cant imagine why they would have you do it this way and then make you change the code for release.

Comment: The problem is that nobody went into the documentation after adding Proguard to say that it will change the method name you have specified in the XML. In other words, the "HomeServicesClick" method is probably renamed to a() or something like that. The XML, unfortunately, isn't automatically updated.